# Symfony + Doctrine - Truncate tables only if a series of foreach ends well

Tags: php, symfony, oop, doctrine

I have in my DB 5 entities:

```
Customer
Location
Machine_1
Machine_2
Machine_3
```

`Customer` is in a `OneToMany` relation with `Location` (one `Customer` can have multiple `Locations`), `Machine_1`, `Machine_2` and `Machine_3` are in a `ManyToOne` relation with `Location` (one `Location` can have multiple `Machines`).

I have already all data of the entities stored in the db.
I have an API service (POST) that can update the data of the three Machines. 
This is how I'm doing that:

```
    /**
    * @Route("/saveData")
    * @Method("POST")
    **/
    public function saveDataAction (Request $request) {
      $data = $request->getContent();
      $dataDecode = json_decode($data);

      if (is_object($dataDecode)) {
        foreach ($dataDecode->customer as $customer) {
          //get data
          foreach ($dataDecode->location as $location) {
            //getdata
            foreach ($dataDecode->machine_1 as $machine_1) {
              //get and set data
            }
            foreach ($dataDecode->machine_2 as $machine_2) {
              //get and set data
            }
            foreach ($dataDecode->machine_3 as $machine_3) {
              //get and set data
            }
          }
        }
```

I need to truncate all the Machinery table before inserting new data, but this have to happen only if everything goes fine inside the `foreach` loops.

Something like this, but only if the remaining part of code executes well:

```
if (is_object($dataDecode)) {
   $em->createQuery('DELETE FROM AppBundle:Machine_1')->execute();
   $em->createQuery('DELETE FROM AppBundle:Machine_2')->execute();
   $em->createQuery('DELETE FROM AppBundle:Machine_3')->execute();
   .....
}
```

How can I do that? Thanks!

Comment: what do you mean "the foreach ends well"? what have you tried and why didn't it work?

Comment: @yivi I mean everything goes well and I don't get any error. I don't want to truncate tables before I know the process of retrieving and setting data ends well.

Comment: And what have you tried?

Comment: I've tried to truncate everything at the start of the controller, but it's not the best solution.

Comment: So you tried doing something different than what you are asking. I meant: _What have you attempted to accomplish this particular result?_

Comment: You should read about providing a [mcve], and reading about this [Question Checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) would also help you in creating great questions, so we can give great answers.  :)

Comment: No, I tried something related to what I'm asking. Thank you for your great help :)

Answer (score 0):

You could use PHP's `Exception` mechanism.
I don't know exactly what you mean by " if the remaining part of code executes well", but you could use something like:

```
/**
* @Route("/saveData")
* @Method("POST")
**/
public function saveDataAction (Request $request) {
  $data = $request->getContent();
  $dataDecode = json_decode($data);

  if (is_object($dataDecode)) {
    try{
      foreach ($dataDecode->customer as $customer) {
        //get data
        if ($something_is_wrong){
           throw new \Exception('message');
        }
        foreach ($dataDecode->location as $location) {
          //getdata
          if ($something_is_wrong){
             throw new \Exception('message');
          }
          foreach ($dataDecode->machine_1 as $machine_1) {
            //get and set data
            if ($something_is_wrong){
             throw new \Exception('message');
            }
          }
          foreach ($dataDecode->machine_2 as $machine_2) {
            //get and set data
            if ($something_is_wrong){
              throw new \Exception('message');
            }
          }
          foreach ($dataDecode->machine_3 as $machine_3) {
            //get and set data
            if ($something_is_wrong){
               throw new \Exception('message');
            }
          }
        }
        //These lines of code will only execute if no Exception is thrown:
        $em->createQuery('DELETE FROM AppBundle:Machine_1')->execute();
        $em->createQuery('DELETE FROM AppBundle:Machine_2')->execute();
        $em->createQuery('DELETE FROM AppBundle:Machine_3')->execute();
      } catch (\Exception $e){
         //These lines will only execute if something went wrong
      }
    }
```

Comment: The data I'm receiving is a JSON file. It can have multiple locations and then multiple machines. If I receive for example 4 customers, It may happen  that a foreach is executed several times. So I need to truncate when the foreach on customer is complete and everything went fine.

Comment: Well, I suppose you can adapt this idea to fit your needs.

Comment: Can you give me a hint? I only have to truncate the tables one time, before inserting the new data coming from the API service.

Comment: mmm this is different to what you asked for, isn't it? You said you had to remove all elements only if there was no error inside the `foreach` blocks...

Comment: Yes, but I explained the general situation. The foreach on `customer` is there because I can have multiple customers, locations, and machines to save. Sorry for any confusion

Comment: I thing you should then open a new question explaining *exactly* your problem.